# C++ double pointer not known conversion

Tags: c++, templates, pointers

I am literally freaking out on the following :

```
template <class T> // int, float, double etc..
class Graph {
public:

  // Documentation, it has to be between [0..100]
  Graph(int size = 10, int density = 10, T range = 0):
    m_size(size),
    m_density(density),
    m_range(range) {
    generate();
  }

  ~Graph() {
     for (int i = 0; i < m_size; i++)
    delete[] m_graph[i];
      delete[] m_graph;
  }

  [..]

  static Graph<T>* custom(T** cgraph, int size, T range) {
    Graph<T> *graph = new Graph<T>(size, 10, range);
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
      delete[] graph->m_graph[i];
    delete[] graph->m_graph;
    graph->m_graph = cgraph;
  }


private:
  T** m_graph;
  [ .. ]
};

int nodes[4][4] = {
  { 6, 5, 2, 5 },
  { 5, 6, 3, 3 },
  { 1, 3, 6, 1 },
  { 5, 3, 1, 6 }
};

int main() {
    Graph<int> *graph = Graph<int>::custom(nodes, 4, 5);
}
```

What is it poorly failing to compile reporting the following errors ?

```
   g++ graph.cpp -o test_graph 
graph.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
graph.cpp:191:55: error: no matching function for call to ‘Graph<int>::custom(int [4][4], int, int)’
     Graph<int> *graph = Graph<int>::custom(nodes, 4, 5);
                                                       ^
graph.cpp:60:20: note: candidate: static Graph<T>* Graph<T>::custom(T**, int, T) [with T = int]
   static Graph<T>* custom(T** cgraph, int size, T range) {
                    ^
graph.cpp:60:20: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘int [4][4]’ to ‘int**’
```

It looks so right to me, what's wrong ?

Comment: you should pass `nodes` not the address of it. `nodes` is a `int**` while `&nodes` is `int***`, without considering the `const` things.

Comment: You need to learn about the difference between arrays and pointers.  `nodes` is an array of arrays of ints.  It is *not* an array of pointers to int.

Comment: @MohamedMoanis:  `nodes` absolutely is *not* `int **`.  It decays to `(int [4])*`

Comment: A cast can make it `(int**) nodes`.

Comment: isn't nodes an int** as m_graph and cgraph ?

Comment: As Martin said, its not a `int**`, but a cast to `int**` will make it.

Comment: See: http://c-faq.com/aryptr/aryptrequiv.html

Comment: @MohamedMoanis:  If you cast `nodes` to an `int**` and use the result, you will invoke undefined behaviour.

Comment: In fact, you should read through all that section of the C FAQ - it talks about C, but this is one of the things that carries over from C to C++.

Comment: In addition, when you call `delete` on the CGraph returned by `custom`, it's going to try and delete the passed in array - that's not going to work.

Comment: I might need to copy it somwhere then, I got you. Is this the solution to the first question:  Graph<int> *graph = Graph<int>::custom((int **) &nodes[0], 4, 5);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make `nodes` by an array of pointers to int.

```
int nodes_v[4][4] = {
  { 6, 5, 2, 5 },
  { 5, 6, 3, 3 },
  { 1, 3, 6, 1 },
  { 5, 3, 1, 6 }
};

int *nodes[4] = { nodes_v[0], nodes_v[1], nodes_v[2], nodes_v[3] };
```

You also need to add an additional member to the Graph variable to mark that it is a custom graph, and if set, the destructor should not delete the memory.

Best to give Graph a private constructor which passes in the `custom` flag and doesn't bother allocating the memory if set.

```
  Graph(int size, int density, T range, bool custom):
    m_size(size),
    m_density(density),
    m_range(range),
    m_custom {
    }

  Graph(int size = 10, int density = 10, T range = 0):
    Graph(size, density, range, false) {
    generate();
    }

  static Graph<T>* custom(T** cgraph, int size, T range) {
        Graph<T> *graph = new Graph<T>(size, 10, range, true);
        graph->m_graph = cgraph;
  }
```

Finally, you need to handle copy constructor and assignment operator (start by just deleting them).